# How to get multiple lines <li> below <ul> tag with regex in python

Tags: python, expression, beautifulsoup

I got this HTML tags that I've pulled from a website:

```
<ul><li>Some Keys in the UL List</li>
</ul>
<li>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Description</li>
<li>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Description\Microsoft</li>
<li>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Description\Microsoft\Rpc</li>
<li>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Description\Microsoft\Rpc\UuidTemporaryData</li>
</ul></ul>

<ul><li>Some objects in the UL LIST</li>
</ul>
<li>_SHuassist.mtx</li>
<li>MuteX.mtx</li>
<li>Something.mtx</li>
<li>Default.mtx</li>
<li>3$5.mtx</li>
</ul></ul>
```

How can I get the lines(text beteween `<li>` tags) between the `<ul>` tags.
They don't have any class to diff then.

I don't know too much about BeautifulSoup and Regex.

I want this result as example:

```
<li>_SHuassist.mtx</li>
<li>MuteX.mtx</li>
<li>Something.mtx</li>
<li>Default.mtx</li>
<li>3$5.mtx</li>
```

Comment: [never, ever, ever, parse HTML with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1190844)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

soup.find(text='Some objects in the UL LIST').findNext('ul').findAll('li')

Thanks @Haidro you let me got some ideas and searchs, thanks for you help and time.

Answer (score 1):

With `BeautifulSoup`:

```
>>> html = textabove
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> soup = BS(html)
>>> for ultag in soup.findAll('ul'):
...     for litag in ultag.findAll('li'):
...         print litag.text
```

Which prints:

```
Some Keys in the UL List
Some objects in the UL LIST
```

---

To get the latter `<li>` tags:

```
>>> for litag in soup.findAll('li'):
...     if litag.text.endswith('.mtx'):
...         print litag
...         
<li>_SHuassist.mtx</li>
<li>MuteX.mtx</li>
<li>Something.mtx</li>
<li>Default.mtx</li>
<li>3$5.mtx</li>
```

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros Check now :)

Comment: Thanks for your help/time @Haidro.
i'll check this tomorrow at the morning, then i post here the feedback.

Comment: Hello @Haidro, this works perfectly bro but ...
The challenge is: Sometimes the object will just have a name and will not end with .mtx as a default to search for them. Like i can search for HKEY as a default in the begning.
MANY times ill get texts that i need to know how many <li> tags has inside the <ul> cuz they can change in each HTML page and having diferent names like "123g","huji","ospdl","asuidh354#!%$". ):

Comment: Will `<ul><li>Some objects in the UL LIST</li>
</ul>` always be that exact same text?

Comment: In this case i just can do too this thing: var = re.findall(r'<li>(.+).mtx</li>', page)

Comment: Yes, in this page they have Titles that i can use to take from the first <ul> after the <li> title to the last </ul>

Comment: I'm not on my current computer at the moment, so I'm not able to post an accurate answer. Sorry. But if that regex solution works for you, then by all means use it.

Comment: Will works if i have extensions and some words as default.
I am trying for days to take the itens from the <ul><li>title</li>(items to take)</ul>

Answer (score 0):

you do not need regular expressions to do that take a look at python's [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)